# How to retrieve pathName from request->file in Symfony 2.8 using $request = Request::createFromGlobals(); ?

Tags: php, file, symfony, request

How to retrieve pathName from `request->file` using `$request = Request::createFromGlobals();`  during custom file upload in `Symfony 2.8` to controller action for reading data from the file (i do not need to save file to database). How to refer to `"pathName"`?  I am not able to retrieve information from file i upload, namely i am not able to get `"pathName"`.

Additionaly, how to submit custom file name together with file. Is this possible?

```
//Controller
<?php

namespace CrmBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Method;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;

/**
 * @Route("/mip")
 */
class MoInPlController extends Controller {

    /**
     * Plots profits, etc..
     *
     * @Route("/m1i1p1d", name="m1i1p1d")
     * @Method({"GET","POST"})
     */
public function m1i1p1dAction()
{  

    $msg[]="";

    $request = Request::createFromGlobals(); 

 if ($request->files->get('fileToUpload')) { 
        if($request->request->get('nameF') ) { $nameF = $request->get('nameF'); }
        print_r('<br> 1. request->files->get(fileToUpload) = <pre>');       var_dump($request->files->get('fileToUpload') ); print_r('</pre>');

        $ftoup=$request->files->get('fileToUpload');
        print_r('<br> 2, ftoup = <pre>'); var_dump( $ftoup ); print_r('</pre>');
        print_r('<br> 3, get_object_vars (ftoup) = <pre>'); var_dump( get_object_vars($ftoup) ); print_r('</pre>'); //empty array
        print_r('<br> 4, ftoup[pathName] = <pre>'); var_dump( $ftoup["pathName"] ); print_r('</pre>'); //empty string

        $msg[]='<br> The file was submitted.';

        $strData = file_get_contents($ftoup["pathName"]); //does not work here
        $jsonData = json_decode($strData, true);

    } else {
        $msg[]='<br> Not upload yet.';
    }

    return $this->render( 'CrmBundle:moinpl:m1i1p1.html.twig',
            array( "mssgs"=>$msg ) ); 
} 
...}
```

Twig template:

```
{% block body %}

<form name="crmbundle_moinpl_m1i1p1" method="post" action="/mip/m1i1p1d" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <br> <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
    <br> Name of file for future refering: <input type="text" name="nameF">.  
    <br> <input type="submit" name="loadF" value="Add File" />
</form>
```

{% endblock %}

The result looks like this:

```
request->files->get(fileToUpload) =

object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile)#1066 (7) {
  ["test":"Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile":private]=>
  bool(false)
  ["originalName":"Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile":private]=>
  string(12) "CompSit.json"
  ["mimeType":"Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile":private]=>
  string(24) "application/octet-stream"
  ["size":"Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile":private]=>
  int(3259)
  ["error":"Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile":private]=>
  int(0)
  ["pathName":"SplFileInfo":private]=>
  string(49) "C:\Bitnami\wampstack-5.6.20-0\php\tmp\php3FCA.tmp"
  ["fileName":"SplFileInfo":private]=>
  string(11) "php3FCA.tmp"
}


ftoup =

object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile)#1066 (7) {
  ["test":"Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile":private]=>
  bool(false)
  ["originalName":"Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile":private]=>
  string(12) "CompSit.json"
  ["mimeType":"Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile":private]=>
  string(24) "application/octet-stream"
  ["size":"Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile":private]=>
  int(3259)
  ["error":"Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile":private]=>
  int(0)
  ["pathName":"SplFileInfo":private]=>
  string(49) "C:\Bitnami\wampstack-5.6.20-0\php\tmp\php3FCA.tmp"
  ["fileName":"SplFileInfo":private]=>
  string(11) "php3FCA.tmp"
}


get_object_vars (ftoup) =

array(0) {
}

ftoup[pathName] =
```

Comment: On another matter, if you are using Symfony standard edition you shouldn't do ``Request::createFromGlobals();`` to retrieve the request, but add it as an argument of your action : ``public function m1i1p1dAction(Request $request)``. See this chapter of the documentation : http://symfony.com/doc/current/controller.html#the-request-object-as-a-controller-argument

Answer (score 3):

Suddenly, i relised that i shall use:

$ftoup=$request->files->get('fileToUpload')->getPathName();

Other useful functions of class `"Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile"`:  "getATime", "getBasename", "getCTime", "getClientMimeType", "getClientOriginalExtension", "getClientOriginalName", "getClientSize", "getError", "getErrorMessage", "getExtension", "getFileInfo", "getFilename", "getGroup", "getInode", "getLinkTarget", "getMTime", "getMaxFilesize", "getMimeType", "getOwner", "getPath", "getPathInfo", "getPathname", "getPerms", "getRealPath", "getSize" or "getType"?

Useful links beside symfony official documentation:

[https://symfony2-document.readthedocs.io/en/stable[http_fundamentals.html?highlight=request ]

[http://www.gdomc.com/0502/how-to-get-the-request-parameters-in-symfony2/ ]

[ http://ebanshi.cc/questions/4002120/publish-a-symfony2-website-webapp ]

[ http://symfony2-document.readthedocs.io/en/latest/components/http_foundation.html ]